# VirtualBox の 起動時にエラー: Nonexistent host networking interface, name 'vboxnet0' (VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR)

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBoxを使いWordPressのサイトをローカルで作っています。

ファイル名（.htaccess）の編集をしてから、VirtualBoxを再起動した際に、エラーが発生しました。
具体的には以下のメッセージが表示されています。

```
仮想マシン"OOO"のセッションを開けませんでした。

Nonexistent host networking interface, name 'vboxnet0' (VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR).

終了コード : NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
コンポーネント: ConsoleWrap
インターフェース: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

ファイル名（.htaccess）の編集の仕方がわからずに、下のコードを入力しました、それがだめだったのでしょうか？
下記のコードでやりたかったことは、キャッシュの保存をさせないことです。

```
# データはキャッシュさせない
ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"
```

直し方があれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: エラーを見る限りはゲストOSの仮想ネットワークアダプタの問題であり、たまたまタイミングが重なっただけで .htaccess の編集が直接問題の原因となっているわけではないように思います。

Comment: ゲストOSってなんでしょうか。

Comment: @y_waiwai もう少し誤解の無いように書いた方が良いかと思います。(おそらくOSの種類を尋ねたいのだと思いますが、質問者の方は "ゲストOS" の意味とは何か聞かれていると誤解しているように思われます) / ちなみに履歴を見ると "ゲストOS" は質問者が書いたものではありません。

Answer (score 1):

たまたまタイミングが重なっただけなのですね、承知しました、
ご回答頂き誠にありがとうございます。

今回のエラーは、再起動した際に直っていることに気付きました。